# Xcode - Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 - Embedded API

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, xcode7.3

I created an Cocoa Touch Framework and was trying to add the framework to my main App. 
I copied the Framework using "`Embed App Extension`"
I also added the Framework inside Linked Binary with Libraries as well.
However, under all circumstances I get the error

> "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"

It throws the MAC-O error if the framework is in the Embedded Binaries, and if the framework in not in the Embedded Binaries but only Linked Frameworks and Libraries, then it throws the following error: dyld: Library not loaded

Any help is appreciated

Here is the critical log file

> 2017-07-04 06:13:11 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items
>   with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an
>   unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=} 2017-07-04 06:13:11
>   +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
>
> Here is the standard log file with error 2017-07-04 06:13:11 +0000
>   [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: Currant, task:
>   Upload 2017-07-04 06:13:11 +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only
>   availaable distribution method
>   
>   2017-07-04 06:13:11 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user
>   entitlements for
>   :
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at
>   "/Users/bhushan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-07-03/Currant
>   7-3-17, 11.13
>   PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Currant.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at
>   "/Users/bhushan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-07-03/Currant
>   7-3-17, 11.13
>   PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Currant.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
>   2017-07-04 06:13:11 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user
>   entitlements for
>   :
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at
>   "/Users/bhushan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-07-03/Currant
>   7-3-17, 11.13
>   PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Currant.app/Frameworks/CurrantApi.framework/Frameworks/SOAPEngine64.framework/Versions/A"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at
>   "/Users/bhushan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-07-03/Currant
>   7-3-17, 11.13
>   PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Currant.app/Frameworks/CurrantApi.framework/Frameworks/SOAPEngine64.framework/Versions/A"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
>   2017-07-04 06:20:07 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant

Comment: can u share your pod file this error occur because of written pods in wrong format.

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Currant' do
pod 'Fabric'
pod ‘Crashlytics'
end

target 'CurrantTests' do
end

Comment: Replace your pod file from the below.

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'Currant' do
pod 'Fabric'
pod ‘ Crashlytics’
end

Comment: It throws the MAC-O error if the framework is in the Embedded Binaries, and if the framework in not in the Embedded Binaries but only Linked Frameworks and Libraries, then it throws the following error: dyld: Library not loaded

Comment: Tried the solution with the podfile, but no change